# How to color an input box depending on the size of varible in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input box which is `disabled`. It gets a variable `x` which is sometimes `< 1` or `> 1`. I want to color the background with `red` if `x > 1`, `green` if `x < 1` and `grey`as a default (`without a value`).
I tried this:

```
    <Field name="testValue" type="number" component={Input} label="Value:"
 onChange={this.changeColor()} id="test"/>
```

the method `changeColor()`:

```
changeColor() {
        let num = document.getElementById("test");
        if(myValue === "") {
            num.css("backgroundColor", "grey");
        } else if(myValue  < 1) {
            num.css("backgroundColor", "green");
        } else {
            num.css("backgroundColor", "red");
        }
    }
```

and in the `constructor`: `this.changeColor = this.changeColor.bind(this);`
Unfortunately I am getting: `Cannot read property 'css' of null`
What I am doing wrong? Is it the correct way? Any help or suggestions is very appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onChange` expect a function but you are assigning the value returned by the function, instead of that write it like this remove `()`:

```
<Field 
   name="testValue" 
   type="number" 
   component={Input} 
   label="Value:"
   id="test"
   onChange={this.changeColor} 
/>
```

But i will suggest you to use these conditions on style tag instead of using `document.getElementById('text')` then applying css on that, we should avoid the direct dom manipulation with react.

Store the value of input field in state variable `myValue` then write it Like this:

```
changeBGColor() {
    let myValue = this.state.myValue;
    if(myValue === "") {
        return "grey";
    } else if(myValue  < 1) {
        return "green";
    } else {
        return "red";
    }
}

<Field 
   name="testValue" 
   type="number" 
   style={{backgroundColor: this.changeBGColor()}}
   component={Input} 
   label="Value:"
   id="test"
   onChange={this.changeColor} 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you used React to render your component. So you should keep in mind, if you are building a React app, that you should not use the `document` anywhere in your code.

Anyway, to answer your question, if you need to render differently according to some value, in react, that value should live in the state of your component.

In the `changeColor` callback, you should read the value of the input and write it to the state of the component:

```
changeColor(event) {
   // event.target is the dom element that emitted the event
   this.setState({ inputValue: event.target.value });
}
```

And then, in your render function, you just give the color to the input depending on the value of the state:

```
render() {
   var fieldColor = "red";
   if (this.state.inputValue === "") {
     fieldColor = "grey";
   } else if (this.state.inputValue < 1) {
     fieldColor = "green";
   }
   <Field style={ color: fieldColor } onChange={this.changeColor}/>
}
```

This way your render depends on the state of the component and the color updates as the user types in.

Now I'd suggest changing the name of the method `changeColor` to something more relevant to what the new function is doing, something like `updateTestValue` maybe?